# Axios post request failing on call with a 404

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios

This is my whole page. yes it is messy, but it shows everything just to make sure there isn't any confusion.

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const EditServicesPage = () => {

const history = useHistory()


  const [myData, setMyData] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [showEditButton, setShowEditButton] = useState(false);

  const [fields, setFields] = useState({
    updatedByCNUM: myData.updatedByCNUM,
    content: myData.content,
    site: myData.site
  })


  var idFromListServicesPage = history.location.state.id
  console.log("22: " +  idFromListServicesPage)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post('/getDocToEdit', {id : idFromListServicesPage})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("line 28 esp.js: " + res.data)
        setMyData(res.data);
        setIsLoading(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const deleteById = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    axios
      .post(`/deleteDoc`, { id: id })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(id, " worked");
        window.location = "/admin/content";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

 
  const handleInputChange = e => setFields(f => ({...f, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}))

  const editById = (id, site, content, updatedByCNUM) => {
    
    console.log(id, site, content, updatedByCNUM);
    axios
      .post(
        '/editDoc',
        ({
          id: id,
          location: site,
          content: content,
          updatedByCNUM: updatedByCNUM
        })
      )
      .then(() => {
        console.log(id, " worked");
        window.location = "/admin/services";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const onClickEdit = (e, _id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var site = document.getElementById("site").value;
    var content = document.getElementById("content").value;
    var updatedByCNUM = document.getElementById("updatedByupdatedByCNUMhide").value;
    console.log(site, content, updatedByCNUM)
    editById(_id, site, content, updatedByCNUM);
  };

  const onTyping = (name, value) => {
    setMyData({ ...myData, [name]: value });
    if (value.length > 0) {
      setShowEditButton(true);
    } else {
      setShowEditButton(false);
    }
  };

  
  return (
    <table id="customers">
         <h1>Edit Services Page</h1>
      <tr>
        <th>site</th>
        <th>content</th>
        <th>updatedByCNUM</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <input
              // ref={site.ref}
              type="text"
              value={myData.site}
              onInput={(e) => onTyping(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder={myData.site}
              name="site"
              id="site"
            />{" "}
              {/* <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={site}
                onChange={(e) => onTyping(e.target.value)}
                name="site"
                id="site"
              /> */}
            </td>
            <td>
            <input
              // ref={content.ref}
              type="text"
              value={myData.content}
              onInput={(e) => onTyping(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder={myData.content}
              name="content"
              id="content"
            />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={myData.updatedByCNUM}
                name="updatedByupdatedByCNUMhide"
                id="updatedByupdatedByCNUMhide"
                readOnly
              />{" "}
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                deleteById(idFromListServicesPage);
              }}
              disabled={isLoading}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
           <button
           
           onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            editById(idFromListServicesPage);
          }}
          >
             Edit
           </button>
            {showEditButton && (
              <button onClick={(e) => onClickEdit(e, idFromListServicesPage)}>Submit Edit</button>
            )}
             </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
  );
};

export default EditServicesPage;
```

basically, what I am trying to do is, when someone types into the input fields, and then clicks submit edit, it will make the axios call. however, it is not doing that right now. It makes the axios request, but fails with a 404 error, that says:

```
XHR POST http://localhost:3000/editDoc

Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

which is strange, because my proxy is set up with a `localhost:3001`, and I have other files running the same way, almost identical code in each file, and those axios requests are working no problem. does anyone know the issue here?

Comment: Check the way import `axios` in the other files

Comment: it is the same :(

Comment: Never. Because you must to declare `proxy` with axios. In your file. you don't have it

Comment: okay but even if I force `http://localhost:3001/editdoc` in there, it still doesn't work. fails with a `cors` error. and this is strange because I don't use cors anywhere in my app, and all other axios calls work fine

Answer (score 0):

404 error means page not found. I think you have a problem with backend.

Check the backend or backend router to see if the API is actually defined. Make sure the `url` and `method` matches.

You can check it using postman, too. If it works on postman, you can use it on front end in most cases except cases of CORS errors.

Comment: yes you were right. I cannot believe I missed that. wow. thank u